# Using Namespace in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, namespaces

I have a namespace `Utilities` in JavaScript, it looks sort of like this:

```
var Utilities = Utilities || {
    printTest: function() { print("test"); }
}
```

I can call my `printTest` function with `Utilities.printTest();` but I am wondering if I can call it with something like

```
var Utilities.....
using Utilities;
printTest();
```

I want it to work similar to how C++ implements namespaces into your code with the `using` statement. Is there anything similar for JavaScript?

Thanks

Comment: No you can't, and what you have is just a regular object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The `with` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with):

```
var a, x, y;
var r = 10;

with (Math) {
  a = PI * r * r;
  x = r * cos(PI);
  y = r * sin(PI / 2);
}
```

Note that it is not allowed in strict mode.

Comment: There's a reason it isn't allowed in strict mode. [It's not a good idea to use it.](http://www.2ality.com/2011/06/with-statement.html)

Comment: @MikeC It's not deprecated - that blog post is heavily biased for no good reason.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for

Comment: @Izkata [It throws an error in strict mode.](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-with-statement-static-semantics-early-errors) As far as I'm concerned that's deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, that's not possible. The closest you can get (assuming the `this` context isn't important) is assigning the functions to individual variables.

```
var printTest = Utilities.printTest;
var otherMethod = Utilities.otherMethod;
...
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no 'using' keyword in JavaScript like there is in C# or other languages.

You can pull in the module or library via a script tag for the client.
Node.js has a 'require' keyword that will you can use in your Node.js application like this: `require("body-parser");`

You can put that statement at the top of a file and Node.js will look up your file structure for that module. It's methods are then available in that file.

Answer (score 0):

The following would give something of a similar functionality (when `this` is defined), but there's a reason `using` is infrequently used in C++: It oftentimes defeats the purpose of having a namespace in the first place. Namespaces exist to isolate independent parts of a design, and if they need to be mashed together like this, it might be worth considering a different structure. That being said, there's a reason the keyword exists, so there are certainly legitimate uses!

```
function using(namespace) {
  if (typeof namespace === 'object' && this !== null && this !== undefined) {
    for (var i in namespace) {
      this[i] = namespace[i]
    }
  }
}

using.bind(this,myNamespace);//attaches the values of namespace to this
```

Again, this pattern isn't really recommended for most cases.

Comment: You have a syntax error (remove the `=>`) and this [doesn't really work like a `using` statement.](https://jsfiddle.net/g54a1u9L/1/)

Comment: Wow that's embarrassing. Changing now! And it works in scenarios where _this_ is defined. In JSFiddle, it's apparently undefined in the global, so I'll add a sentence about that. (All the more reason for this not to be a pattern.) Thanks for the catch.

Comment: While it may be true that the global scope is `undefined`, that's not entirely the problem. [You can't access the members directly by name](https://jsfiddle.net/g54a1u9L/4/) without a preceding `this.`. A `using` statment doesn't require `this.` so it's a close approximation but not quite right.

Comment: Absolutely. More of a forced attempt than anything else, which really doesn't fit the spirit of `using` in the first place.